# Cron doesn't work in Magento1.7

Tags: bash, magento, cron

I use Magento for my shopping, and I want to give all logged-in users have 3% discount for all products, so I wrote a rule, but it only worked for two days and after two days I had to re-apply it again, my Cron setting in Magento admin is:

```
Generate Schedules Every: 60
Schedule Ahead for:10
Missed if Not Run Within:60
History Cleanup Every:120
Success History Lifetime:120
Failure History Lifetime:120
```

To solve this problem, I wrote a Cron job in DirectAdmin panel to call `cron.sh` file in root of Magento (`cron.sh` is a shell script file that call `cron.php`), but it did not work properly, please guide me to solve this problem.

Cron job setting in Directadmin panel is:

```
0 0 * * *    /usr/local/bin/php /home/noorantel/domains/nooran.com/public_html/shopping/cron.sh >> /home/noorantel/domains/nooran.com/public_html/shopping/var/logfile.txt
```

Comment: This cron should run daily at midnight, can you confirm your script doesn't get called by adding a print in the very beginning of `/home/noorantel/domains/nooran.com/public_html/shopping/cron.sh`. BTW why are you running a `.sh` script with `php`? My best guess is that you should replace `/usr/local/bin/php` by `/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 0):

So firstly the Magento cron should run with the following regularity.

```
*/5 * * * *
```

This will mean that it will run every 5 mins.

Secondly you seem to mix up what type the file is either you need to run the php version or the bash version but what you seem to be doing is trying to run the bash version with php. Try the following.

```
*/5 * * * *  /bin/sh /absolute/path/to/magento/cron.sh
```

Or

```
*/5 * * * *  /usr/local/bin/php /absolute/path/to/magento/cron.php
```

Comment: i did it,but didn't work proprly, there is a point that i did not talk about, before, I was wrote a CronJob in DirectAdmin ,my rule worked for only one day after that,I was  changed cron in magento's adminpanel similar to that something explained in my Post ,then my rule worked for two days.mybe it's related to cron setting in magento adminPanel..